# Do you know any broker in Europe that has american ETFs available in their offer?

Tags: etf

Due to some new law from 2018 you can't buy in Europe american etfs like SDPR S&P 500, iShares Core S&P 500 or others. Do you know ANY European broker who allows i? I found only DIF Brokers who has that (not intend to advertise anything just wanna find another broker). I'am not interested in american CFDs, only in american ETFs. Thanks

Comment: No broker will let you circumvent the law. However, you will likely be able to find an ETF that tracks the same index *and* complies with EU regulations.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed since MifidII which requires ETFs issuers to provide new documentation compliant with EU laws, the foreign ETF universe has been greatly reduced for EU retail investors (which does more harm than good in my opinion). For smaller issuers updating documentation is obviously not a priority since I've seen no change during the past 2 years. However, you can find some (but not all anymore) Vanguard and BlackRock iShares ETFs with brokers such as DeGiro or Interactive Brokers, and probably SaxoBank too.